# how to generate unrepeating random layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

```java
public class Music extends Activity {
    private int [] layouts = {
            R.layout.question_selector,
            R.layout.question_selector2,
            R.layout.question_selector3,
            R.layout.queston_selector4,
            R.layout.question_selector5,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int i = layouts.length;
        Random r = new Random();

        while (--i > 0) {
            int j = r.nextInt(i + 1);

            //swap values
            int temp = layouts[j];
            layouts[j] = layouts[i];
            layouts[i] = temp;

        }
        setContentView(layouts[i]);
    }
}
```

Here's what i have done so far: it works just fine, but I have notice that there are times that some layouts are shown over and over again. What I want is that when I press the button and it generates a layout randomly, the next time I'll press the button again it should not repeat the layout that had been shown before. How can I do such thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `arrayList` and then `shuffle` it instead of an array with Random, this will make it random but only use every item once

EDIT, code example:

```
     ArrayList<int> mArrayList = new ArrayList<int>;
        //OR ArrayList<int> mArrayList = new ArrayList<int>(Arrays.asList(mOrdinaryArray));
     mArrayList.put(R.blabla.blabla);
     mArrayList.put(R.blabla.blablatwo);
     Collections.shuffle(mArrayList);
     Log.d(TAG, "output after shuffle: " + mArrayList);
```

Comment: it means that i should declare it as an arrayList instead of an array only? and then i should randomize the arrayList?

Comment: Yes, so instead of array, make an arraylist then you call `Collections.shuffle(mArrayList)` and then you can go through it from position 0 to end because it's already been randomized

Comment: i try to make it in arrayList but when i press the button i got an error "force close". is it possible to display the layouts in arrayList?

Comment: don't use Random any more, when you shuffle the list it is randomized and you can go through each position with a simple for or while loop, also remember in an arraylist it's `mArrayList.get(i);`